# MongoDB Java - Add or Update an Array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have Order collection:

```
{
orderId: "A1",
items: [ 
{itemId: "i001", qty: "20", description: "whatever..."},
{itemId: "i004", qty: "10", description: "whatever..."},
....
]
}
{
orderId: "A2"
...
}
```

How can i **add or update an item**, depending on **itemId** being present or not - against a order document?
A typical update would result in qty change for an itemid.

addToSet (adds if not present, but does not update) and push (always adds) - does not seem to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use the The positional $ operator.

This is an exemple using your collection :

```
db.Order.update({itemId : "A1", 'items.itemId' : "i001"}, {$inc : {'items.itemId.$.qty' : 10}});
```

but be careful to only use it with an update query vecause it doesn't work with an upsert

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with a Bson filter?  Using the MongoCollection updateOne method?

https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-